# rapply "replace" not behaving as expected

Tags: r

I am using R to search a list for subelements that are lists of length 0 and replace those subelements with vectors. I thought this code using `rapply` would work:

```
temp1 <- list(issn = "", essn = "2042-8812", pubtype = list(), recordstatus = "PubMed", pubstatus = "258")
temp2 <- rapply(temp1, function(x) length(x), classes = "list", how = "replace")
stopifnot(!identical(temp1, temp2))  ## fails as temp1 and temp2 are identical
```

Interestingly, if I do (what I believe is) the exact same thing, but using a conditional statement in `lapply`, I get the expected result:

```
temp3 <- lapply(temp1, function(x) if (class(x) == "list") length(x) else x)
stopifnot(!identical(temp1, temp3))  ## succeeds as temp1 and temp2 are not identical
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong with `rapply`, but I can't figure out what. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you want to use `rapply` here; there is nothing to recurse through, and `lapply` would suffice. But perhaps this is a simplified example. Additionally, `?rapply` states that *"[i]f ‘how = "replace"’, each element of ‘object’ **which is not itself list-like** and has a class included in ‘classes’ is replaced by the result of applying ‘f’ to the element."* (bold face mine). If I interpret this correctly, a function can only be applied to non-`list`-like objects, and `classes = "list"` therefore would make no sense.

Comment: Yes, this is a simplified example; the real data have multiple layers of nested lists. But I think "which is not itself list-like" is the key. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure & done ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `?rapply` documentation (bold-face mine)

```
This function has two basic modes.  If ‘how = "replace"’, each
element of ‘object’ which is not itself list-like and has a class
included in ‘classes’ is replaced by the result of applying ‘f’ to
the element.
```

So `rapply` with `how = "replace"` won't work on `list` elements.